# CTAN Mirror Integrity - Miktex Update

Tags: miktex, ctan, security

Does the Miktex Updater ensure that the downloaded packages from a CTAN mirror are not corrupted in comparison to the original version?

When looking up the update log there are messages about a "database digest", but no verify message for a single package is ever appearing.
Additionally, there is a "mpm.ini" file containing hashes for all (?) packages. But if this file is downloaded from the mirror itself (contained in miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma), this could have been changed, for this specific mirror, with malicious purpose.

I'm not interested if the files are malicious to begin with ([How do CTAN maintainers make sure all the uploaded packages and classess in CTAN are free of malicious code?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103056/how-do-ctan-maintainers-make-sure-all-the-uploaded-packages-and-classess-in-ctan)), but if there are changes to their original versions.

Is there any checking done when updating to ensure the equality of mirror to original files? I could not find any explanation on this topic.