# History of Writing Mathematical Texts

Tags: symbols

I am writing a paper and would like to add something about the history of `TeX` and `LaTeX` and the difficulties of writing mathematical texts before the creation of `TeX`. Does anyone have any indication of material (books and/or articles) with this information! I would also like to quote information from the linotype typewriter.

Comment: While not devoted specifically to the historical aspects, "The Elements of Typographic Style", by Robert Bringhurst covers many aspects of history when showing elements of modern typography (https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/44735.The_Elements_of_Typographic_Style).  And a history of Zapf is always a good read: http://download.linotype.com/free/howtouse/ZapfBiography.pdf

Comment: Before TeX, when I was a grad student, IBM Selectric typewriters were used (changing to symbol balls when needed -- but still easier than writing in symbols by hand).  Troff was around then but most profs preferred the appearance of the IBM typed papers.  When we finally installed TeX, the typewriters were put aside.

Answer (score 9):

There are two published articles on the history of TeX:

- Communication of Mathematics with TeX, in Visible Language 50:2,
  http://visiblelanguage.herokuapp.com/issue/202/article/1362
- TeX: A Branch in Desktop Publishing Evolution, in two parts, in the IEEE Annals of the History of Computing; Part 1: http://www.ams.org/publications/dtp-tex-part-1.pdf ; Part 2: https://www.computer.org/csdl/magazine/an/2019/02/08726056/1ascitM5OiA

Re composition in metal, Linotype is not suitable for the task of composing mathematics.  The preferred machine was Monotype.  See

- The Monotype 4-Line System for Setting Mathematics, by Daniel Rhatigan, http://ultrasparky.org/school/pdf/Rhatigan_Monotype_4-line_math.pdf
- Setting Mathematics, by Arthur Phillips, http://www.metaltype.co.uk/downloads/mr/mr_40_4.pdf

An earlier question in this forum has dealt with this topic: [Typesetting before TeX and computers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/244082).  This deals mainly with mechanical methods.

As to what triggered the creation of TeX: [Where's an example of the bad typesetting that inspired TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/367058)  (More can be found by searching on the tag "TeX history".)

Troff was an early computer program from Bell Labs for typesetting math.  It was available only at academic sites with Unix hardware.  This question covers the territory rather thoroughly: [TeX & Troff a reflection on the history of Computer Typography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39442)

There were also several "user level" computer programs available in the early days of personal computers.  I'm looking for a question identifying those; I'm sure it exists.

Comment: The links posted help a lot, however, don't there is still some more complete text with the history of Latex too! If anyone has any indication, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at my *A Few Notes on Book Design* (`texdoc memdesign`) and section **1.6 Setting Maths** which describes how typically maths was typeset in the days of lead type and hand-typesetting before TeX made things so much easier.